# Using isset() to check for empty fields and if the field is empty it should jump to the else statement but the statement is not working

Tags: php, html

I'm using an `isset` to check for empty fields and if the field is empty it should jump to the else statement but the statement is not working.

```
<pre>
if(isset($_POST['make'])){
    if(is_numeric($_POST['mileage']) && is_numeric($_POST['year'])){
         $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO autos (make, year, mileage) VALUES ( :mk, :yr, :mi)');
        $stmt->execute([
                        ':mk' => $_POST['make'],
                        ':yr' => $_POST['year'],
                        ':mi' => $_POST['mileage'])
                    ];
         $_SESSION['success']="Added successfully";
         header("Location: view.php");
         return;
                
      }else{
        $_SESSION['error']="Mileage or Year must be numeric.";
        header("location:add.php");
        return; 
      }
 }else{
    $_SESSION['error']="Make is required.";
    header("location:add.php");
    return; 
 }
</pre>
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: isset() - Determine if a variable is declared and is different than NULL. It better you empty() for check emptyness

Comment: thank you @mail2bapi. i tried using is_null() but still didn't work. empty() worked as expected.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?and what is the output that you are getting

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty) instead of [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check the emptyness.

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

And if you use `isset` it will return `TRUE` if the variable is set and the value is not `NULL`

> Determine if a variable is considered set, this means if a variable is declared and is different than NULL.
> isset() will return FALSE when checking a variable that has been assigned to NULL. Also note that a null character ("\0") is not equivalent to the PHP NULL constant.